# QComboBox::setModel emits editTextChanged, how to block this?

Tags: qt, qcombobox

I am setting a model to `QComboBox` on `editTextChanged`. While setting a model it again emits an `editTextChanged` signal on editTextChanged. I am using an SQL like query for filtering combobox items.
pls help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can temporarily disable all signals emitted from `QComboBox` using `blockSignals(ture);`

```
QComboBox* combo = /* ..... */

combo->blockSignals(true);
combo->setModel(newModel);
combo->blockSignals(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could [`disconnect`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#disconnect) the signal from the slot(s) before setting the new model, and connect it again afterwards.